# Cannot connect to on-prem SQL Server with Google Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to test a connection using Cloud Data Fusion to connect to an on-prem SQL Server. Our GCP Project does not use the default network but rather a custom VPC.

It's important to note that security is very important as this database contains healthcare data.

We currently have App Engine Flex code that uses pymssql to query the database on this SQL Server through the VPC, and want to test using Data Fusion.

I have copied and added the generated data fusion service account to IAM with role Cloud Data Fusion API Service Agent.

I have configured in Data Fusion

```
system.profile.properties.network = <VPC name>
```

I have verified that the username and password for authentication to SQL Server are valid for the database.

THE VPC network allows port 22 and 1433.

At this point I am just trying to get a successful connection to query a table in the database.

Here is the error message I get:

> Connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can access SQL Server from GCP (via AppEngine Flex Py code) but having trouble connecting through Data Fusion. It also looks like authentication doesnt seem to be a problem (as the error message is around connection).

One area I can think of is to try Cloud Data Fusion private IP, that allows you to securely connect to your VPC from Cloud Data Fusion. This is a new feature and you will need Data Fusion product team support to leverage this feature.

Comment: Please check https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-private-ip